# Mysql warnings at one server and errors at other server

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL server. I am trying to update a query using the function `str_to_date(dateofbirth,'%M %d,%Y')`.

I was trying at the Ubuntu server and it was executing with few warnings wherever the date format varied. But it is giving me errors at the Windows OS and unable to execute the query saying incorrect date value.

Is this MySQL server version problem or any settings where errors can be changed to warning.

Comment: Can you check the contents of the `dateofbirth` string?

Comment: I'd suggest the most likely culprit is "%M" in your format - depends on OS language settings it may or may not recognize , for instance, "January" as the 1st month. Check the value you store in the table.

Comment: Database collation is tied to the OS, so you can see differences across OS's using perceivabley the same DDL and DML. What Collation are you using and how are the DB's setup, the same? Please edit your question and add more detail around the configuration and DDL